# Grab value from nginx location path

Tags: nginx

I'm setting up nginx as an API router.

How can I grab a specific portion of the "location" path and dynamically populate it into proxy_pass? For instance:

location /users/v2/ { 
proxy_pass http://app.domain.com/api/{{users}}/v2; 
}

I need to grab whatever is in the first field, in this case "users", and pop it into the proxy_pass path.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find your original question and your comment to the answer a bit contradictory. But to answer your requirement from the comment, you can use a `location` block like this:

```
location ~ ^/(users)/v2/(.+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://app.domain.com/api/$1/v2/$2;
}
```

I assume that the paths also contain other things after the `/v2/` here. I capture the other stuff into `$2` to use in the `proxy_pass`.

If you want to allow only specific strings in addition of users, you can use the `|` rule for OR match:

```
location ~ ^/(users|admins)/v2/(.+)$
```

A generic rule for regex captures in nginx is that any regular expression inside parentheses is captured in a variable. First parentheses content is captured into `$1` and so on.

Of course there are exceptions to the rule. `(?:users)` makes nginx not capture the value. `(?<variable>users)` captures the value into variable called `$variable`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little more complicated if you want to use the variable inside an `if()` block. This does not work:

```
location ~ ^/(users)/v2/(.+)$ {
    if ( $http_user_agent ~ 'Googlebot' ) {
        # Does not work: $1 and $2 are undefined in this scope.
        proxy_pass http://app.domain.com/api/$1/v2/$2;
    }
}
```

However, you can save the values and then use them in the nested block:

```
location ~ ^/(users)/v2/(.+)$ {
    set $base $1;
    set $resource $2;
    if ( $http_user_agent ~ 'Googlebot' ) {
        proxy_pass http://app.domain.com/api/$base/v2/$resource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but its something like if you just want before the `/v2`

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/v2/ {
    proxy_pass http://app.domain.com/api/$1/v2;
}
```

Comment: the location must be hardcoded with /users/ in that block. would that still work? also, i'm embarassed to say i don't know exactly how the $1 - $9 variables work, does that just mean the field? in this case, will $1 expand to whatever is on the first field of the location?

Comment: $1-$9 get populated from the location regex search. So the first one from left to right inside the `()` so in this case whats in `(.*)` gets set to $1 so if its /users/v2 $1 is users and /foobar/v2 then $1 would be foobar

Comment: location ~* /users/v2/ {
    proxy_pass http://app.domain.com/api/$1/v2;
}

Comment: so just 'users' would qualify as regex as long as ~ is used?

Comment: no.. `^` means the start so anything between the first two `/`'s gets put into $1

Comment: Taken literally, `location ~* /users/v2/` qualifies as a regular expression, it uses case-insensitive match. As an example, it matches a path like `/some/other/path/UsErS/V2/something`, since the regex string is in the path. However, it is not recommended to use such relaxed regex, because it can lead to unexpected behaviour.